# Should Stack Overflow introduce an [opinion-based] tag?

Tags: feature-request

I propose that Stack Overflow creates a new tag for moderators to mark opinion-based questions instead of putting them on hold. My arguments in favor of such tag are the following:

- Opinion-based questions tend to capture the experiences of several people regarding one subject in a single place, which contrasts with reading about such subject in dispersed web pages without a formal review/vote system like that of Stack Overflow
- Such questions would not be put on hold or closed by a few members when it is the case that other members like the question (the tag would avoid fruitless discussions about the reasons to put on hold).
- With such a tag, it will be easy for those who do not like opinion-based questions to ignore them, and others to contribute at will.
- The vote system already in place will help to determine the quality of the discussion around an opinion-based question.

I would like Stack Overflow to consider the addition of this tag, or some other mechanism to highlight opinion-based questions, instead of barring the rich answers and discussion they can get generate.

Comment: The problem with such questions is not that they are not easy to avoid; it's their existence here in the first place.

Comment: You forget that SO is not a place for discussion.  It is supposed to be a facts-only Q&A site.  Introducing this tag would only cause SO to become cluttered with off-topic questions.

Comment: @iCodez So why aren't all such questions cleared from StackOverflow instead of hanging around as [closed]? Perhaps because they are useful to many readers ...

Comment: @mljrg A huge number of them *are* deleted, you just don't see them because they're...deleted.  A large percentage of closed but not deleted questions aren't deleted simply because it's so much harder to get questions deleted, and a fair bit less motivation to have content deleted as well.  Keep in mind that many of these questions are also not deleted *yet*, which is of course different from not being worth deleted.

Comment: What @Servy says. Also, they aren't deleted automatically and immediately to give them a chance to be improved or give the community the chance to reconsider the on-hold status.

Comment: I propose an [off-topic] tag.  Simply place the tag on any off-topic question and POOF! it's now on-topic!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two very simple points against this:

- It would be a meta tag. We don't allow those.
- Opinion based questions aren't good for the site, don't really fit the Q&A format and are simply never going to happen.

So no, it's really not necessary nor desirable.

Comment: if such questions are not a good fit as you say, why are not all of them deleted from StackOverflow? I see many [closed] questions because they are not constructive or because they are opinion based still hanging around with lots of readers. What do you have to say about this?

Comment: That we close them to indicate that they shouldn't be asked. But at the same time we acknowledge some of the content might be found useful, and we grant them the privilege to remain on the site for others to benefit from, even if we don't think they are a good fit. "Not a good fit for Stack Overflow" != "Useless altogether"

Comment: Ahah, so in that case you should let such question to be open for a while (one year, for example), instead of putting them on hold immediately thus blocking others to provide useful answers. Then after that period of time, someone would check the "usefulness" (vote counting?) and if the question had few votes then eliminate it completely, otherwise leave it there. In my case, I have made and reworked a question (not this one) that I think may generate useful answers but unfortunately is blocked ...

Comment: I can't speak for your question, but in the general case absolutely not. Such questions do more harm to the site's quality than good. Any such questions are actively closed and deleted at this point. Any old questions that are still around either have not been deleted because they didn't gather such attention, or were found to be on the limit, but had some good content to preserve. That doesn't at all mean we should allow a significant amount of crap to come in, only for us to filter out the gems if there are any at all. That will not improve the site one bit.

Comment: I don't know if you can help me or not, but I have this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366993/how-does-lisp-flavored-erlang-supports-some-features-found-in-other-lisps) that was put on hold and that I think will provide useful answers. What can I do about it?

Comment: Several problems with that one @mljrg. The last bullet point is a no go. It's just doesn't fit. The rest are simply too many questions for a single question. And even individually they are not really the kind of practical programming problem for the site. Like the comments state, an LFE specific forum/mailing list/website might be better for it. Interesting questions, but the scope of SO is somewhat narrow and I don't really see an easy way to reformulate it.

Comment: do you think I have a chance if I place those questions in SO separately and remove the last question? or should I go straight to another forum as you suggest also?

Comment: Perhaps try one @mljrg. Not all. Take the first one and make it more practical. Along the lines of "This is how I do it in Lisp, but now I'm working with LFE. How can I achieve the same thing with that". Then it's more practical and focused. Perhaps that will go over better. But it's not my cup of tea, so don't take my word for it.

Answer (score -7):

Good questions. I'm sorry to see that this had under-ranked - this is exactly the place to ask such questions, and even if the answer is BIG NO - the question itself it still good.

Furthermore - IMHO the answer is BIG YES. because, as Google and the net becomes more effective, Stackoverflow becomes more dispensable. You can see it yourself - the first guys that comes here got plenty of reputation for answering some simple Python questions, for instance. for such questions, in 2016, you totally don't need Stackoverflow.

What I'm REALLY need today? not a data, but an experience... I need a data about thing that I didn't reach before, so I even can't ask about them! And, I'll have to use my wisdom to judge which answer to accept and which not. How can someone do this? I guess it's one of the things that make someone be a good programmer or not...

So, when Stackoverflow in on the train to saturation, maybe you (or me) should bring-up such platform (mind-overflow :) )

Comment: Feel free to make your own site for such questions. Might even work while your community is small enough.

Comment: Did you really just kick a two year old question with the sole motivation of _"but I want to read other people's experiences"_? We already have a massive quality problem with people answering factual questions. Opinion-based answers are _very_ subject to endless discussion and inexperienced people spewing their opinion, which in the end help noone. A discussion forum is the place you're looking for, and the useful ones are ... rare.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe... and you guys stay here and continue with the opinion-witch-hunting ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster I fully understand you, but the need is still exist. Maybe Stackoverflow isn't the platform for it. I can leave with that. But, if such question is got under-rated like this, in this meta forum - we should check if this resistance is professional or just like following the herd...

Comment: Trust me, the resistance against opinion-based questions is entirely professional.

Comment: More than once I found the best answers in questions that have been closed as opinion-based. In some cases I've got the feeling that the opponents didn't understand the question, otherwise they could have provided an answer based on facts.